# Angular 4 Kendo grid expand detail template by clicking on the row instead of the arrow

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I found this link but it has been a while so I wanted to see if this has been implemented. I had a hard time finding a solution to what I am trying to accomplish.

[Opening the kendoDetailTemplate programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786124/opening-the-kendodetailtemplate-programmatically)

Comment: What is the issue? Are you stuck somewhere in code or asking us to help you do something?

Comment: A user would have to click on the arrow to expand the detail template. I'd like to accomplish the same thing by clicking on the row instead of the arrow. I can't find a way to do this at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize the `cellClick` event, and the `expandRow` function to open the detail-row, when the user clicks a cell.

Detailed information on those options (and more) can be found on their [API Reference](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GridComponent/).

#### *.html

```
<kendo-grid
    (cellClick)="onCellClick($event)"
>
    ...
</kendo-grid>
```

#### *.ts

```
onCellClick(event: CellClickEvent) {
    event.sender.expandRow(event.rowIndex);
}
```

I've also prepared a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mZ2DTGALkkJRFmXmKFNZ?p=preview) to show the code above in action.

Comment: Thank you Philipp, that worked! But is there any way to trigger the cell click event by a double click instead?

Comment: Not that i know of, but you could use the same event and check if there are two clicks within a certain time-frame.

Comment: i logged out the event from the cellclick event and there is a type: "click". If only there was a way to change that to a "dblclick".

Answer (score 0):

declare you viewChild

```
 @ViewChild('grid') private grid;
```

then call the below method from onclick. Pass row index as param.

```
 expandRow(i: number) {
  this.isRowExpanded = !this.isRowExpanded;
  this.isRowExpanded ? this.grid.collapseRow(i) : this.grid.expandRow(i);
}
```

You can get the row index by

```
ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex"
```